# Proper application of De LHospital's rule

Tags: limits

Question under topic of 'DeLHospital's rules'
Determine the values of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ae^x+b\cos x}{x}$$ exists and equals 2. State and prove all necessary conditions when applying DeLHospital's rules

My attempt was:
the function $f(x)=x$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\neq0$ in every neighborhood of $0.$ Also
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$$
Now, define the function $g(x)=ae^x+b\cos x$. Then 
$$\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0\Leftrightarrow a=-b$$
Then, **IF** we suppose that $a=-b,$ then we can apply DeLHospital's rule and show that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ae^x-a\cos x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}(ae^x+a\sin x)$$
Then
$2=a$ and thus $b=-2.$ By the uniqueness of the limit, $2=a=-b.$
Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

Note we can also proceed by standard limit

- $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\to 1$
- $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to \frac12$

as follows

$$\frac{ae^x+b\cos x}{x}=a\frac{e^x-1}{x}-bx\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}+\frac{a+b}x$$

for the existential of the third limit we need $a+b=0 \iff b=-a$, that is

$$\frac{ae^x-a\cos x}{x}=a\frac{e^x-1}{x}+ax\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to a\cdot 1-a\cdot 0\cdot \frac12=a$$

and therefore $a=-b=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ae^x+b\cos x}{x} \rightarrow \frac{a+b}{0}.$$
For L'Hospital rule to proceed $a+b=0$. Next, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{ a(e^x-\cos x)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{a(1+x-1+x^2/2)}{x}=a.$$
So $b=-a$ and $a$ is arbitrary it cannot be fixed.